# Xcode stops debugging the app suddenly

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode4.3

I'm encountering a mysterious issue while debugging on a device from Xcode. At some point, Xcode stops running the application that results a crash of the application on the device without giving me any warning or errors in the console and even the app is not running anymore in Xcode.

NOTE: my app download about 30Mb at first start up then parse them and it contains several complex views, so it might be that the iOS stops the application for some reason(memory issue)but i'm not sure!!!

any clue/idea/suggestion to find/track this king of issues would be appreciated

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSLog and break ponts or "Struments" to analyze the of memory:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Definitely intercept memory warnings.

Check the console, look for SigKill, EXC_BAD_ACCESS, and code 9, all of which are probably memory. Other SO questions/answers will tell you how to find the console logs. Also, you're probably duplicating a question or so, I'd check for similar posts first. iOS App crashing is a good start-phrase.

Good luck, and always, read the Views and View Controllers Programming Guide (or similar name) Guide to get a grasp on it.

Comment: nothing in the console and even i cant put the command "bt all" becuase xcode stop running the application

Comment: Did you register to receive memory warnings and output a log statement?